# iOS: Can't get content of Caches directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Trying to get content of Caches directory:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *path = [[self.class cachesDirectoryURL] absoluteString];
NSArray *directoryItems = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

`path` is correct, I can see in Finder that it exists and contains my files.
`directoryItems` is `nil` and `error` is

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Caches” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7982d2d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}, NSFilePath=file:///Users/seelts/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1411C3D-91FB-4D91-83A4-D0747071AE36/data/Containers/Data/Application/800DE429-F10C-438E-BB04-2948C0B07E7C/Library/Caches/, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
)}
```

What's wrong with me?

Comment: What is self.class? What is the value of path?

Comment: Are you sure about the "/Containers/Data/Application/800DE429-F10C-438E-BB04-2948C0B07E7C" part of the path being a match for what's on disk?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using wrong path. To get right cache directory for the app use this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

In `cacheDirectory` you will receive string path like this (whithout `file` scheme):

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D55805E2-50FF-4D8D-8D04-490001AD6071/data/Containers/Data/Application/DE437461-E0F8-4C11-861E-2D1C56CDF6F1/Library/Caches
```

The whole code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error;
NSArray *directoryItems = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cacheDirectory error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", directoryItems);
```

Comment: So, my mistake was to use `absoluteString` method. I've changed it to `NSString *path = [[self.class cachesDirectoryURL] path];` and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional information to @shpasta's answer here.
Suppose you have additional folders inside your Cache directory and you wanna get some files inside those folders. 
This is how you can get access to files inside those folders.

```
 NSArray *subFolders = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]subpathsAtPath:yourCacheDirectory];
 NSString* additionalParams;

for(NSString* sub in subFolders){
            if([sub containsString:@".log"]){
                 //Assuming you have .log file inside the folder.
                additionalParams = sub;
            }
        }

 NSString* fullFileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",cacheDirectory,additionalParams];
```

Hope this helps anybody who is trying to get access to files inside folders which exits inside cache directory.